# Is it possible to download a file while disk space is below a certain threshold?

Tags: bash, scripts, hard-drive

Is it possible to download a file while disk space is below a certain threshold in a bash script? I'm asking because I'm downloading files from an online database, and would like to keep downloading until my storage passes a pre-determined threshold. Once that happens, I'd like to stop the download (i.e terminate the command), delete a few files, then restart the download (i.e rerun the command that downloads the file). Based on my understanding, you can't "pause" a command in bash, and in my case it's fine to just stop the download process and do it again.

Comment: Yes, it certainly must be possible with a relatively simple bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this script](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-script-to-watch-the-disk-space.html) which does most of what I need